# How to inherit variable set to folder to files in the folder

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, document, folder, inheritance

I have a SP site with document library. In the document library I have custom choice column. I would like to ask, if there is away, if I set value in the folder level, if all files in the folder could inherit the same choice in the choice column.

Would flow work here? I have never done flows.

Thank you.

Comment: This is not possible using SharePoint out of the box functionality for default folders. You can try using document set instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using SharePoint out of the box functionality for folders (SharePoint default "Folder" content type).

Instead of using these folder content type, you can use **Document Sets** in SharePoint.

Follow Microsoft documentation given below:

1. [Introduction to Document Sets](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/introduction-to-document-sets-3dbcd93e-0bed-46b7-b1ba-b31de2bcd234)
2. [Create and configure a new Document Set content type](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-and-configure-a-new-document-set-content-type-9db6d6dc-c23a-4dcd-a359-3e4bbbc47fc1)

Comment: Thank you Ganesh, however I was to create an App in Power apps, that would search in the document library and would do the filtering based on values in the choice columns of the library. Is there really no way how to inherit the variables? If I have let´s say in folder 50 files, can´t  I create a flow or something that would populate the variables that are on folder level to the files in the folder? Thank you

Comment: You maybe be able to do it using a scheduled flow. But you have to consider all scenarios like if there are folders within folder, how many folders are in the library, how many total files in the library. Flow will take some time to run based on that